# Trying add background image?

Tags: css, jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

On my layout, I have 3 pages.xhtml: Top, Body and Footer. These pages are contained at `<p:playout/>` in template.xhtml 
I'm trying add a background image in page Body.xhtml, but the image doesn't display in all area.

How can I do display image at all area of page ?

Here how I'm trying

**template.xhtml**

```
<p:layout fullPage="true">
            <p:layoutUnit position="north">
                <ui:include src="/template/top.xhtml"/>                
            </p:layoutUnit>

            <p:layoutUnit position="center">
                <ui:include src="/template/body.xhtml"/>                
            </p:layoutUnit>

            <p:layoutUnit position="south">
                <ui:include src="/template/footer.xhtml"/>
            </p:layoutUnit>
        </p:layout>
```

**body.xhtml**

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"> 
    <h:head>
        <title>Facelet Title</title>

        <style>
            body{
                background-image: url("#{resource['imagens/background.png']}");
                width:100%;
                height:100%;
                background-repeat: no-repeat; 
                background-attachment:fixed;            
            }
        </style>

    </h:head>
    <h:body>

  eu sou o body (I'm body)

    </h:body>
</html>
```

**and the result**

[image]

Comment: Please note the typo in response: the "imagens" has an extra 'n'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`body {
    background-image: url("#{resource['imagens/background.png']}");
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat; 
    background-attachment:fixed;

}`

Comment: nice. But the image is opening like in image that I posted.

Answer (score 1):

just try giving this:

```
    <style>
        body{
            background-image: url("#{resource['imagens/background.png']}");            
        }
    </style>
```